# How do I check if a nuget package supports Universal Windows App (UWP)?

Tags: nuget, win-universal-app

I am building a Xamarin application. Currently Supporting Android and iOS.

I would like to expand my application to Universal Windows App using the [Xamarin guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/)

Before doing so I would like to check whether the nuget packages I am currently using support Universal Windows App

For example I have been trying to check if Xamarin.Insights supports Universal Windows App and checking the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Insights/) page I can't see any mention of supported platforms

The contents of the actual nuget package but as I don't know what I'm looking for I can't tell from here either

[image]

So what am I looking for in the package to check if a nuget package supports Universal Windows App?

Comment: Supposed method is really trial and error... That's why Xamarin offers the component store, where they only add packages where they checked xamarin support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UWP app will look in folders in the following order:
uap10.0 > uap > netcore451 > netcore > dotnet

Without these folders there isn't a **guarantee** that the library will work, but it might. There's some trial and error in this as class library targets are undergoing a large overhaul in NuGet and .NET Core. [Oren Novotny has a great post on it](https://oren.codes/2015/06/09/pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp/) and there's a [NuGet](http://blog.nuget.org/20150729/Introducing-nuget-uwp.html) post on UWP specifically.

[image: NuGet folder order]